# Support of $f \in A$ in Spec $A$ for a reduced ring $A$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

Let $A$ be a reduced ring (i.e. no nilpotents). Take any $f \in A$
and I would like to show that $\operatorname{Supp} f = \overline{D(f)}$, where $D(f)$ 
denotes the distinguished open set of $\operatorname{Spec}A$ where $f$ does not vanish.
I think that the fact that reducible is crucial here, but somehow my argument
doesn't use this fact. I can't see where I am going wrong and I would appreciate some 
assistance. Thanks!

Comment: If you have an argument then you should post it.

Comment: If you write \operatorname{Supp}f instead of Supp\ f, then not only will "Supp" not be italicized, but proper spacing before and after it appears automatically without being put there manually.  I changed it.

Comment: You write "I think that the fact that reducible is crucial here". No,  it is "reducedness" which is crucial: "reducible" means something else, and is irrelevant here.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Yes, thank you! I definitely meant "reducedness"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Given a scheme and a global section $f\in \Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X)$, the support of $f$ is the set of points $x\in X$ where the germ of $f$ is non-zero: $f_x\neq0$ .
Note carefully that this subset $\operatorname {supp} f\subset X$ is trivially closed (since its complement is open by the very definition of "germ" !)  and that you need not  take its closure.

2) In the case of an affine scheme $X=\operatorname {Spec} A$ the support of $f\in A=\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X)$ is thus the set of prime ideals $\mathfrak p\subset A $ such that $\frac 01\neq \frac f1\in A_\mathfrak p$.
If for example $A$ is a domain the support of any $f\neq 0$ is $\operatorname {supp} f=\operatorname {Spec} A$,

3) The slightly counterintuitive example above is explained as follows:
Given a global section $f\in \Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X)$, it has a value $f(x)$ at every $x\in X$, namely: $$f(x)=\operatorname {class} f_x\in \kappa (x)=\mathcal O_{X,x}/\mathfrak m _x$$ We may then consider the subset $Z_X(f)\subset X$ of points $x\in X$ where $f(x)=0$ and its complement $$D_X(f)=X\setminus Z_X(f)=\{x\in X|f_x\notin \mathfrak m_x\}\subset X$$ Since obviously   $f_x\notin \mathfrak m_x\implies f_x\neq 0$   we have $D_X(f)\subset \operatorname {supp} f$ and thus (since this last set is closed) $$\overline {D_X(f)}\subset \operatorname {supp} f$$[Thanks to user tracing  for reminding me to mention this fact, which I had forgotten to state in my original answer]

In the important special case of an affine scheme $X=\operatorname {Spec} A$   we have $$\kappa (x)=\mathcal O_{X,x}/\mathfrak m _x=A_\mathfrak p/\mathfrak pA_\mathfrak p=\operatorname {Frac}(A/\mathfrak p)  $$
and so $Z_X(f)=\{\mathfrak p\in \operatorname {Spec} A|f\in \mathfrak p\}=V(f)$.
This by the way proves that for a general  scheme $X$ the subset $D_X(f)\subset X$ is always open (but not closed in general).

4) All of the above has nothing to do with reducedness!
Reducedness comes in when you wonder what it means for  a function $f\in A$ to have value zero everywhere, in other words what does $Z(f)=\operatorname {Spec} A$ mean?
Answer: it means that $f\in \bigcap \mathfrak p= \operatorname {
Nil} A$.
Hence  **if $A$ is reduced** we have $Z(f)=\operatorname {Spec} A\iff f=0$ .
However given  a field $k$ and the non-reduced ring $A=k[T]/(T^2)=k[\epsilon]$,   the "function"  $f=\epsilon $ is zero everywhere although its support is all of $\operatorname {Spec} A=\{(\epsilon)\}$.

Comment: Dear Georges, I just want to note that one can say say more in the direction of your point (4) in relation to the OP's question, namely: the further statement that $D(f) \subset \operatorname{Supp}f$ (since at points of $D(f)$ non-vanishing of the germ of $f$ is clear, since even the value of $f$ in $A/\mathfrak p$ is non-zero), and so $\overline{D(f)}\subset\operatorname{Supp}f$. However in general this inclusion is not an equality (as your example with the dual numbers illustrates), but it is an equality when $A$ is reduced (which is what the OP seems to trying to prove).

Comment: Dear @tracing, thank you for your comment: indeed I had wanted to state that inclusion and then forgot! I have edited my answer in order to take your excellent comment into account.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, reducedness is crucial for this.  In general, all you can say is that $\operatorname{Supp} f$ contains $\overline{D(f)}$.

---

You might want to consider the ring $k[x,y]/(xy,y^2)$, taking $f = y$.  One
has $D(y) = \emptyset,$ but $\operatorname{Supp} y$ is equal to the closed point $(x,y)$.  (Georges's example with the dual numbers, taking $f = \epsilon$, is another good illustration of how your statement fails in the non-reduced case.)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see a proof of the claim in the posts above, so I thought I'd post one.
Suppose $A$ is reduced, and $p\in supp(f)$. We want to show that $p \in \overline{D(f)}$.  Let $D(g)$ be a basic neighborhood of $p$. We want to show $D(g)$ intersects $D(f)$, i.e. we want to show that there exists a prime ideal $q$ which contains neither $f$ nor $g$. If no such $q$ exists, then every prime ideal contains either $f$ or $g$. But this means every prime contains $fg$. But $A$ is reduced, so the intersection of all the prime ideals is zero. Thus $fg=0$. But recall that $g\notin p$, and thus $f/1= 0$ in $A_p$, contrary to the assumption $p \in supp(f)$.